# parsing <sup> tag inside <html:text>

Tags: java, struts

Struts tag

```
<html:text property="Number" readonly="true"/>
```

The property 'Number' holds some number with '#' in superscript

So it's like:

```
4452<sup>#</sup>
```

But the text field doesn't read the sup tag as html tag instead as a string. Is there a way I can prevent that?

Comment: I've formatted the `<sup>` tag in code - not sure if that is what is required here. Clearly it was needed for the `<html:text>` tag. Feel free to edit further if necessary.

Comment: It's a text input, you can't render HTML inside a text input.

Comment: isn't there any way I can do this??